# 301 Redirect URLs with capital letters and more than one forward slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to permanently redirect URLs with capital letters and any number of forward slashes that appears after domain root back to the root.
Examples:

> http://www.example.com/abc/pqr/23423532

(this has 2 forward slashes)

> http://www.example.com/AngryBirds

(this has 2 capital letters)

Should be redirected to http://www.example.com/

Tried the following in https://www.regextester.com/

```
^(.*[\/?)$
^([\w]+)(\/+)$
^([A-Z]+)(\/?)
```

How can I write the regex expression to match these requirements?

Comment: You can show your current rules which you've tried/attempted.

Comment: Added them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Z]+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([/]{2,})
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R=301]
```